# Encriptación y desencriptación app.config

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy realizando una conexion con encryptacion pero me sale error quisiera que me ayuden. este es el error que me sale como la imagen [image: Este es el error que me sale]

```
private void btnRegistrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Configuration conf = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    conf.ConnectionStrings.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");
    conf.Save();

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("creacionusuario", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("IdUsuario", txtid.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Usuario", txtusuario.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Contrasena", txtcontrasena.Text);
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Se Procedio al Desbloqueo");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ocurrio Un error en el Desbloqueo");
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Por lo que veo le estás pasando la cadena de conexión sin desencriptar. Algo así: `var decryptedConnStr = Decrypt(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString);`. Y luego pasarla por parámetro a la inicialización de `new SqlConnection(decryptedConnStr)`.

Comment: @migueladanrm ME Podrias ayudar por favor amigo te lo ruego

Comment: ¿Con qué estás encriptando la cadena de conexión? No podés pasarla por parámetro encriptada, primero debes descifrarla a texto legible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Piero, en tu caso estás utilizando una encriptación personalizada, pero en caso quieras encriptar y desencriptar la información de la cadena de conexión de un archivo de configuración (app.config) podrías considerar:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Permite encriptar y desencriptar la cadena de conexión de un AppConfig
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="encriptar">Acción de encriptar o desencriptar</param>
    /// <param name="rutaEjecutable">Ruta del ejecutable al que se quiere encriptar su cadena de conexión de su App.Config</param>
    private void EncriptarAppConfig(bool encriptar, string rutaEjecutable)
    {
        // Obtener configuracion actual
        var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(rutaEjecutable);

        var section = config.GetSection("connectionStrings") as ConnectionStringsSection;
        if (section == null) throw new NullReferenceException("Section connectionStrings no existe");

        if (encriptar)
        {
            // Encriptar
            if (section.SectionInformation.IsProtected) return;

            section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");
        }
        else
        {
            //Desencriptar
            if (!section.SectionInformation.IsProtected) return;

            section.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection();
        }
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder pero igual me sale el mismo error en la foto @Davlio

Comment: el probema me sale en :
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString);

Comment: ayudame por favor

Comment: @PieroFloresEspinoza, déjame revisarlo nuevamente. o en todo caso envíame al correo (Ver perfil).

Comment: te enviado a tu correo o esta ruta amigo te agradesco un monton esto como 2 semanas no encuentro ninguna solucion 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-MwdGfv7cJiS3cwWndHRWdILVk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: amigo @Davlio te enviado a tu correo tambien el link gran amigo

Comment: @PieroFloresEspinoza si tuvieras dudas de discusión te invito a participar en el chat de SOes: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol.

Comment: Revisando tu codigo veo que la linea:
`ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString`
Te trae el valor encriptado.
Que método usaste para generear el valor de 'conn'?

`<add name="conn"  connectionString="ldqksWYPns61m/iPjagdmlq5c7baa3qiXoIrSa4La+rY2cs7RbcFrP6CMHCcHRwfB27fGZnAcWX8R2f6jzssc+jnQkaeOrtbgb946Etbw7k="  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>`

Comment: @Urrestarazu.Ale, la cadena encriptada que estaba en su cadena de conexión lo realizaba con **utilitario** que solo tenía la función de encriptar y **no desencriptar**. Por lo que llegué a revisar era una encriptación Triple DES, [mira el ejemplo](https://jorgepedraza.wordpress.com/2011/01/29/funcion-cifrado-net/)

Comment: Si no tenes la información del algoritmo de encriptación que usa no vas a poder obtener la información de la cadena de conexión.

Comment: @Urrestarazu.Ale, por eso la solución que le planteo en mi respuesta le doy otra alternativa de encriptación.

Comment: Yo tenía ese gran problema con esto ya que mi aplicación también se distribuye, lo que ahora hago es usar LocalDB y ahí con las características de SQL Server, encripto toda información crítica.